Which areas of Statistics make use of complex analysis
As the title says, what areas of statistics make use of complex analysis?
This question is motivated by the fact that IIT Kanpur has a compulsory course on complex analysis in its Statistics(Masters), while IIT Bombay does not.
Note: I looked up the answers here, from which it seems that:

Complex analysis is useful for mathematical maturity
Useful for a better mathematical understanding of functions used in mathematics

Also, I know that the normal distribution can be extended to complex variables. But I am not able to find where these kind of distributions would be appled.

Directional statistics, characteristic functions in probability, certain topics in time series, as well as contour integration arising from different contexts all require complex analysis to some extent.

Good to hear. Unfortunately, the question has been closed, so you can't add an answer.

Where would you use contour integration in statistics?

One example is the frequency domain approach to time series analysis. One of the key objects there is the spectral density function which is defined as the discrete-time Fourier transform of the sequence of the autocovariances.
